# Unconventional approaches for learning to play scales?

Tags: guitar, scales

I'm a guitar player who started learning theory a bit later down the road, and there is a practical issue that I can't figure out how exactly to tackle. That would be **scales**, more precisely, the ability to 'see' them on the fretboard and improvise or compose with them without needing to stare at some chart. I understand how they're built, I just need to be able to apply them.

**The internet is full of lessons about scales, so why am I here?**

Nearly every lesson I saw consists of playing one scale up and down 'till the cows come home, then moving on to the next. I feel like that approach **opens more problems than it solves**. The internet is crawling with guys who have issues playing up and down the neck and overall breaking out of those exercise routines. Plus, they are often presented as school lessons (a million things to just learn sequentially), without paying enough attention to their similarities, and how it all connects.

**So I was thinking of some alternative, less conventional approaches:**

One idea was to practice locating just **root** patterns first, then expand into different arpeggios, and finally throw in the rest (maybe it could simultaneously create the habit of 'resting' on arpeggio notes). Things like modal mixture sound a lot easier if you know the notes 'by heart' instead of thinking in  fifty billion different charts.

Another idea was learning the **entire** fretboard, I already have some system for that, and I figured, maybe if I could instantly know where each note is, just knowing the notes of a scale could be enough for me to 'see' what I need to play.

Third idea was to memorize just tiny little **2-3 note chunks** (what you'd play on just one string in just one scale position), what notes they contain, and how they relate to each other then stack them like jigsaw puzzles

And so on.

**Finally, my main questions would be:** What are your suggestions for fast and efficient ways to learn common scales in western music? Do any of my ideas have potential? Do you have more ideas to add? Or is playing up-and-down drills kinda like democracy/capitalism - it sucks, but it's the only thing that actually works?

**Let me know what you think, and thanks for reading. Cheers!**

Comment: I'm not convinced at all that learning arpeggios leads to learning scales, especially in an improvisation or composition context. All learning arpeggios does is let you learn chord tones **and not nonchord tones**, leading to music that risks sounding lame unless your harmonic rhythm is something like chord changes every quarter note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar idea is presented in Aebersold's Jazz Handbook p. 9–10 https://www.jazzbooks.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=FQBK
Start with playing just roots of the chords, and then expand from there with scale pieces, whole scales and arpeggios. This works not only for learning scales, but also switching scales according to harmony.

Another practice technique (to practice a single scale) is to avoid patterns entirely, but rather challenge yourself to play random notes from the scale at various parts of the instrument. This helps to have a better overview of all notes on the whole instrument.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed I wasn't the only one with such ideas. Thanks for your reply!